# How can I hide multiple divs that have the same id?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My HTML

```
<div id="a">Showcode</div>
<div id="b">Code 1</div> // b1
<div id="b">Code 2</div> // b2
```

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#b').hide();
})
```

I am trying to hide all of the id="b" divs at once.

When I run my code I see div id = b  (b1) hide but div id = b (b2) does not.

Answer (score 2):

HTML element IDs must be unique. Use a class name instead, which doesn't have to be unique.

```
$('.b').hide();
```

If for some reason you can't change the HTML, then you can use this, which works for duplicate IDs:

```
$('*[id="b"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `many same id`

```
<div id="a">Showcode</div>
<div id="b">Code 1</div> // b1
<div id="c">Code 2</div> // b2
```

You can use class instead

```
<div clas="a">Showcode</div>
<div clas="a">Code 1</div> // b1
<div clas="a">Code 2</div> // b2
```

**In Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.a').hide();
});
```